# Как вывести код, если на странице имеется класс о определенным текстом?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как вывести код, если на странице имеется класс c определенным текстом?
Например, если в `<div class="nalichie">+</div>` значение `+`, вывести на этом месте `<div class="in-stock">В наличии</div>`, если значение не совпадает - ничего не выводить.

```html
<div class="nalichie">+</div>
```

Comment: Вы уже попробовали что-то сделать?

Comment: Пробовал вот так: `<?php 
$instock = array("+");
if (in_array("+", $os)) {
    echo "+";
}
?>`

Comment: Это что? Где тут `<div class="in-stock">В наличии</div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке документа
        let nal = document.getElementsByClassName('nalichie'); // Получаем все элементы с классом
        [...nal].forEach(function (c) { // Для каждого элемента с классом проверяем
            if (c.innerText == '+'){ // Если текст в поле == +, то...
                c.className = 'in-stock'; // Меняем класс элементу
                c.innerText = 'В наличии'; // Меняем текст элемента
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
    <div class="nalichie">+</div>
    <div class="nalichie">-</div>
    <div class="nalichie">+</div>
    <div class="nalichie">+</div>
    <div class="nalichie">-</div>
    <div class="nalichie">-</div>
    <div class="nalichie">+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="nalichie">
        <? $arr = array( '-', '-', '+', '-', '+', '+', '+');

        foreach ($arr as $l => $v) {

            if ($v == '+') { ?>
                <div class="in-stock">В наличии</div>
            <?}
        }
    ?>
    </div>
```